# Convert two rows to two columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I would like to convert every two rows to two columns using `awk`.

input.txt:

```
# Query: gi|11465907|ref|NC_001872.1| Chlamydomonas eugametos genome, complete genome
# 0 hits found
# Query: gi|11465922|ref|NC_000892.1| Pedinomonas minor genome, complete genome
# 1 hits found
```

output.txt:

```
Chlamydomonas eugametos genome 0
Pedinomonas minor genome 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your input file is consistent:

```
awk -F'[|,]' '/genome/ {printf "%s ", $5; next} {print substr($1,3,1)}' input.txt > output.txt
Chlamydomonas eugametos genome 0
Pedinomonas minor genome 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk -F'[|] |,' '{getline p; split(p,H," "); print $2,H[2]}' file
```

Which would rely on no additional commas in the `|` separated fields.

A bit more robust in that sense would be:

```
awk -F'[|] *' '{getline p; split($5,Q,","); split(p,H," "); print Q[1],H[2]}' file
```

---

A sed alternative:

```
sed 'N; s/.*| *//; s/,.*\n#//; s/ hits found//' file
```